# Solutions for inheriting from two distinct groups of classes without Interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, testing, dry

I am creating an automated test suite modeling classes after web pages. I'm testing web portals with the same basic structure, but differences exist between the portals. For data and methods common to all my web pages across all portals, I want classes to inherit from a class, `BasePage`. There are also methods common to all web pages for a particular portal that don't exist on other portals, so I'd like to inherit from a class, `<portal name>.BasePage`.

Here it gets tricky. I also want to inherit methods from the kind of page I'm on e.g. `BaseForgotPasswordPage`. If my test navigates to the *Forgot Password* page of a particular portal, I'll instantiate `<portal name>.ForgotPasswordPage` and I want it to gain access to the methods in `BasePage`, `BasePortalPage`, and `BaseForgotPasswordPage`. This leaf class needs to inherit from both `BasePortalPage` and `BaseForgotPasswordPage`, which Java won't allow for good reason. They also cannot inherit from each other without creating a ridiculous amount of classes because `BaseForgotPasswordPage` applies to all portals, not just one. Therein lies the problem.

Using Interfaces will lead to duplicate code across different classes and I want to keep my code DRY so that won't help. Consolidating the base classes will give a page behaviors it shouldn't have. For example, if I merge `ForgotPasswordPage` into `BasePage`, every web page will have methods only applicable to the *Forgot Password* page.

A possible constraint that could ease the design complexity is disallowing data in one of the classes like `BaseForgotPasswordPage`. In effect, this class become a module and won't need to be inherited. Albeit not as clean of an approach, it's the only viable solution I could think of. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer since I don't know what each class looks like. How about you do multi level inheritance - 1) BasePage 2) BasePortalPage extends BasePage 3) BaseForgotPasswordPage extends BasePortalPage?  Also you don't have to inherit in order to reuse code. Alternatively some people might also argue "Composition over inheritance". You can just have the object and use its method and such. For example, BaseForgotPasswordPage has instance objects for BasePage and BasePortalPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can use a default method implementation in interfaces together with a composition. Something like this:

```
public interface BasePage {

    BasePage basePageImpl = new BasePageImpl();

    default void basePageMethodOne() {
        basePageImpl.basePageMethodOne();
    }

    default void basePageMethodTwo() {
        basePageImpl.basePageMethodTwo();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BasePageImpl implements BasePage {

    public void basePageMethodTwo(){
        System.out.println("Hello from Base Page method two");
    }

    public void basePageMethodOne(){
        System.out.println("Hello from Base Page method one");
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface BasePortalPage {

    BasePortalPage basePageImpl = new BasePortalPageImpl();

    default void basePortalPageMethodOne(){
        basePageImpl.basePortalPageMethodOne();
    }

    default void basePortalPageMethodTwo(){
        basePageImpl.basePortalPageMethodTwo();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BasePortalPageImpl implements BasePortalPage {

    public void basePortalPageMethodTwo(){
        System.out.println("Hello from Base Portal Page method two");
    }

    public void basePortalPageMethodOne(){
        System.out.println("Hello from Base Portal Page method one");
    }
}
```

---

And now we can build our BaseForgotPasswordPage which is composed of BasePage and BasePortalPage

```
public class BaseForgotPasswordPage implements BasePage, BasePortalPage {

    public static void main(String ... x){

        BaseForgotPasswordPage myPage = new BaseForgotPasswordPage();

        myPage.basePageMethodOne();
        myPage.basePortalPageMethodOne();
        myPage.basePageMethodTwo();
        myPage.basePortalPageMethodTwo();
    }
}
```

and a result is:

```
Hello from Base Page method one
Hello from Base Portal Page method one
Hello from Base Page method two
Hello from Base Portal Page method two
```

---

**========= EDIT =========**

> One question, why do we need the BasePageImpl and BasePortalPageImpl
>   classes? My guess would be this is a Composition design constraint?

No, it's not composition constraint.
It's because interface's features are limited, it would be a little difficult to make an implementation in the interface itself.
Consider the below short example:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    int someVar = 20;  // no error 
    int var2;  // compile time error

private int myPrivate = 30; // error - only public, static & final are permitted

    MyIterface(){  // Constructor - compile time error

    }

    MyIterface(int parameter){  // Another constructor - compile time error 
    }

    default int someMethod( int parameter){
        int someOtherVar = 30;
        someVar ++; // compile time error - someVar is a final field, cannot be modified
        return someVar+parameter;
    }
}
```

As you see from this example - you can't declare constructors, you can't declare fields, cannot use private fields - only final public & static fields are allowed, but they can't be modified - they are simply constants.
It's easier to do it in a delegate - a real class. The interface is only a proxy.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was looking for thank you. One question, why do we need the `BasePageImpl` and `BasePortalPageImpl` classes? My guess would be this is a Composition design constraint?

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thank you!